# What are the standard errors of the predictions from predict.lm in R?

Tags: r, regression, prediction

In R, `?predict` says:

> If the logical se.fit is TRUE, standard errors of the predictions are calculated.

An example:

```
> predict(lm(mpg ~ wt + cyl, data = mtcars), se.fit=TRUE)$se.fit
 [1] 0.6011667 0.4976294 0.7252444 0.4602669 0.7752706 0.5178496 0.7267482 1.0000172 0.9793969
[10] 0.5108741 0.5108741 0.6544576 0.6819424 0.6718159 1.1525645 1.2633704 1.2125441 0.7270859
[19] 0.8820281 0.7988791 0.7380797 0.7442464 0.7773252 0.6623197 0.6616629 0.7700721 0.7322422
[28] 0.9282190 0.9023791 0.5342815 0.7267482 0.8176667
```

How are those standard errors defined?  How are they calculated?

I looked at the `predict.lm` code, and it has a lot of branches.  An excerpt of the code is something like:

```
ip[, i] <- if (any(iipiv > 0L)) 
            as.matrix(X[, iipiv, drop = FALSE] %*% Rinv[ii, 
                                                        , drop = FALSE])^2 %*% rep.int(res.var, 
                                                                                       p)
# ... se later returned as "se.fit"
se <- sqrt(ip)
```

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression) defines the standard error of the betas (slope of a 1-dimensional predictor), but not the standard error of the predictions.

How is `se.fit` defined, using some standard notation?

Related (or the same?), how is it computed?

Comment: I believe this post has what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38109501/how-does-predict-lm-compute-confidence-interval-and-prediction-interval

Answer (score 6):

As suggested by its name, se.fit returns the *standard error of the fit*. This is the standard error associated with the estimated mean value of the response variable at given values of the predictor variables included in a linear regression model fitted with the lm() function in R.

Here is some R code that verifies that for a simplified model with just wt as a predictor of mpg:

```
# model
m = lm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars) 

# model summary
summary(m) 

# residual degrees of freedom 
summary(m)$df[2] 

# 95% confidence interval for the mean value of mpg for ALL cars 
# represented by the ones in the mtcars dataset which have 
# wt = 3.2
p <- predict(m, newdata = data.frame(wt = 3.2), se.fit=TRUE,     
         interval="confidence")

p

# reported interval (lwr, upr) SHOULD be constructed as 
# fit +/- t(alpha/2,n-2)*se.fit
# where t(alpha/2,n-2) is a critical value from the 
# t distribution with n-2 degrees of freedom and 
# alpha = 0.05

# compute the critical value
crit <- qt(p= 0.05/2, df = summary(m)$df[2], lower.tail = FALSE)
crit

# check that computing the half-length of the interval and 
# dividing it by the critical value gives the same result 
# as that reported by se.fit
(p$fit[,"upr"] - p$fit[,"fit"])/crit
```

This excellent post illustrates the difference between the *standard error of fit" and the "standard error of prediction" and gives the formulas used to derive the two quantities.

Comment: What "excellent post"?

Comment: @Isabella Ghement ?